# How would you translate "le guance magre, scavate nel volto" in English?

Tags: translation, english-comparison

I am having troubles translating this expression into English. I know the expression "hollow cheeks" exists, but I can't find a way to translate "scavate nel volto" using the same structure (e.g., *carved into the face*; which appears to be wrong, unfortunately).

Comment: *which appears to be wrong* according to whom? What is the context?

Comment: Hi @nico. The author is describing the main character of the book: "Gli occhi neri appaiano ancora più bui per colpa di quelle due dita di occhiaie che li incorniciano. Le guance magre, scavate nel volto". I searched for 'carved into the face' on Google and it seems the phrase is only used in a realistic (and quite graphical) way.

Comment: If your problem is how to say something in English, then this is a question about English language, not Italian (even if the cue came from an Italian text). If it is about the comprehension of an Italian expression (independently on how to say the same in other languages), please rephrase your question.

Comment: (I took the liberty of correcting *guancie* into *guance*.)

Comment: *Cut out in the face*?

Comment: Also, "*emaciated, deep-sunken cheeks*"?

Comment: As I am finding with translations in the opposite direction, it is not necessary to have a direct translation of a local or idiomatic way of saying something. Communicating the idea is the most important thing in writing or speaking. I believe that your expression is conveying an image of someone with hollow, emaciated facial features, as suggested by the comments above.